# Gremlin / Bulbflow: how to get an integer result out of execute()

Tags: python, django, neo4j, gremlin, bulbs

Sorry if this question is too stupid to ask... I am a newbie on Python+Django+Bulbs+Neo4j.

I am attempting --without success-- to get an integer produced by g.gremlin.execute() while using Python+Django shell, as detailed below.

First, the query in Neo4j's Gremlin console:

```
gremlin> g.v(2).out
==> v[6]
==> v[4]
==> v[8]
==> v[7]
gremlin> g.v(2).out.count()
==> 4
```

What I intend to do it to get this result in Python+Django shell, passing it to a variable, as tried below:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> from bulbs.model import Node,Relationship
>>> g = Graph()
>>> sc = " g.v(vertex_id).out.count()"
>>> params = dict(vertex_id = 2)
>>> val = g.gremlin.execute(sc,params)
>>> val
<bulbs.neo4jserver.client.Neo4jResponse object at 0x243cfd0>
```

I can't get any further from now on.

```
>>> val.one()
<bulbs.neo4jserver.client.Neo4jResult object at 0x2446b90>
>>> val.one().data
>>> val.one().results
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Neo4jResult' object has no attribute 'results'
```

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw result data is going to be in the Result object's `raw` attribute:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> from bulbs.model import Node,Relationship
>>> g = Graph()
>>> script = " g.v(vertex_id).out.count()"
>>> params = dict(vertex_id = 2)
>>> resp = g.gremlin.execute(script,params)
>>> result = resp.one()
>>> result.raw
```

NOTE: `result.data` returns an element's property data, so it will be empty unless you are returning a vertex or edge, i.e. a node or relationship in Neo4j parlance.

See...

- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L60
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L88
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L167

To see what Neo4j Server returned in the server response, you can output the `Response` headers and content:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> from bulbs.model import Node,Relationship
>>> g = Graph()
>>> script = "g.v(vertex_id).out.count()"
>>> params = dict(vertex_id = 2)
>>> resp = g.gremlin.execute(script,params)
>>> resp.headers
>>> resp.content
```

And if you set the loglevel to `DEBUG` in `Config`, you'll be able to see what's being sent to the server on each request. When `DEBUG` is enabled, Bulbs also sets the `raw` attribute on the `Response` object (not to be confused with the `raw` attribute that is always set on the `Result` object). `Response.raw` will contain the raw server response:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph, DEBUG
>>> from bulbs.model import Node,Relationship
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.config.set_logger(DEBUG)
>>> script = " g.v(vertex_id).out.count()"
>>> params = dict(vertex_id = 2)
>>> resp = g.gremlin.execute(script,params)
>>> resp.raw
```

See...

- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/config.py#L70
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py#L221
- http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/#enable-debugging

To turn off `DEBUG`, set the loglevel back to `ERROR`:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import ERROR
>>> g.config.set_logger(ERROR)
```

See...

- http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/#disable-debugging